# Renaming WooCommerce Subscription status

Tags: php, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, status, woocommerce-subscriptions

I've seen code to change WooCommerce's Order status references, how do I adjust this to change WooCommerce Subscriptions statuses? I'd like to change "Active" to something else:

```
function wc_renaming_order_status( $order_statuses ) {
    foreach ( $order_statuses as $key => $status ) {
        if ( 'wc-completed' === $key ) 
            $order_statuses['wc-completed'] = _x( 'Order Received', 'Order status', 'woocommerce' );
    }
    return $order_statuses;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
add_filter('wcs_subscription_statuses', 'custom_wc_order_statuses', 10, 1);

function custom_wc_order_statuses($subscription_statuses) {


    $subscription_statuses['wc-active'] = _x('Order Received', 'Subscription status', 'woocommerce-subscriptions' )

    return $subscription_statuses;
}
```